# Adding controls at runtime in wpf

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks, wpf-controls, runtime

I have a WPF application in which I add controls to the window at runtime as in the code below:

```
tempImg = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
tempImg.Width = 65;
tempImg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Imagesic_web_64h.png"));
tempImg.Tag = text;
tempImg.ToolTip = text;
presenter.webLinks.Add(text);
ExtraContent.Items.Add(tempImg);
```

In the above code ExtraContent is a `listbox`. My question is that if I keep the above in a loop to add multiple image controls to the `listbox` then would it lead to a memory leak?

I have similar code at a lot of places and i can observe that once this window is opened and the controls are added, the memory usage goes high, as expected but even after closing this window the memory does not come down.

Can anyone provide any pointers to this?

Answer (score 2):

The observed behaviour may result from the fact that WPF caches BitmapImages in memory. I guess you could disable caching by setting the [BitmapcacheOption.None](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption.aspx) flag while loading images:

```
var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Imagesic_web_64h.png");
bitmapImage.EndInit();
tempImg.Source = bitmapImage;
```

And i should add that you may encounter degraded performance when caching is disabled, especially when images are used multiple times.

Comment: I have tried disabling the caching but that does not help either. The resources are yet not freed up and as you suggested there is a considerable performance hit as there are a lot of images that are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

When you close the Window there is no guarrantee that resources will be freed.

In .NET it is custom to only free resources when there is a lack of memory. This saves time.

You could disable caching as mentioned by @Clemens but, obviously, you might see a drop in performance due to the lack of caching.

Do not claim a memoryleak too soon; you might be wrong. Test for it.

Comment: I understand that resources are claimed back only on lack of memory but i have seen the application's private byte usage go upto 1 GB and staying there despite closing the window which initially caused the raise in private bytes.

Comment: Still, if there is no need for the 1 GB, why release it?